# How can I manually interpolate between two CATransform3Ds?

Tags: objective-c, swift, core-animation, catransform3d

I have both a start and end `CATransform3D` that I would like to manually animate between. That is, I would like to calculate the intermediate transform for time `t` = 0 (start) to 1 (end). The transforms are a combination of translate and scale, if that matters.

I realize that Apple provides a number of ways to automatically animate from a start to end state, but in my particular use case I actually need to compute the intermediate transform at a given time.

Comment: This can get very tricky. Consider for example a non-center rotation. A simpler interpolation might end up with a value that's on the straight line between the start and end positions, but the in-between value that you are expecting is a non-center rotation by an angle that's in-between the start and end angles of the rotation.

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist I was a worried that the general case might be difficult. For my particular case I just need to interpolate translation and scaling, hopefully that's more tractable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general case is a stinker. The specific case is easier. Assuming you start with the identity transform I would suggest simply writing code that interpolates the values of your scale and translation setting, creating a new transform for each frame, and then applying that transform.  Changes to scale and translate are both mathematically simple. Rotation would be a more expensive (read slower) calculation since it involves trig.

Comment: I actually did end up writing a function that would interpolate corresponding matrix values, but only m11, m22, m33 (the translation values) and m41, m42, m43 (the scale values). The process of doing that made it clear to me that these were all independent of each other, and so doing what you suggest produces the exact same result, only far more cleanly.

Comment: Sure, but the functions that modify the scale and translation values of a matrix only act on those entries in the matrix anyway, and should be quite fast.